# Fl5150 in 3-wire application

Tags: phase, dimmer

I was curious to navigate through the datasheet of FL5150/FL5160 phase cut dimmer IC:
[Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/fl5150-d.pdf)

and for circuits that operate on 220v, there is only a 2-wire application in the datasheet, how can we use a 3-wire biasing for 220v mains?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 3 wire circuit layout (Live, Load, Neutral) as shown in figure 4 of the datasheet, but scale the resistors to reflect the higher voltage. Pay particular attention to R1/R2 and the zero crossing/current sense resistors.
I'm guessing from your question that you have no experience with mains voltage circuits.
Read up on how to design and build mains voltage circuits before trying this out.